# How does Diffusion based Neural Compression actually compress images?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, image-compression

I was reading a paper giving an overview on neural compression (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.06533.pdf) and it mentioned lossy image compression with diffusion models. I am confused because, from what I understood, diffusion models work by applying Gaussian noise to an image and then using a neural network to repetitively denoise it. I don't understand how this would "compress" the image, since wouldn't the noisy image be the same size/memory as the original? I tried reading a paper from Theis et al. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.08889.pdf) to understand, and from what I gathered it seems that the bitrate (bits per pixel) decreases for more noisy images. I read an article from Synced (https://syncedreview.com/2022/06/27/googles-novel-lossy-compression-method-targets-perfect-realism-with-only-a-single-diffusion-model/) that summarizes Theis et al.'s research, which states "By introducing varying degrees of Gaussian noise, the model can flexibly communicate data at arbitrary bitrates".

From what I gather from all of this is that diffusion based neural compression works because the noisy image can be communicated at a lower bitrate than the original image, but what confuses me is why that is the case? Is there some algorithm that allows for images that have Gaussian noising applied to them to be communicated at a lower bitrate? Is there a way to implement this algorithm in Python? Is there a way to calculate the bitrate for a Gaussian noise-ified image?

Please let me know if I am completely misunderstanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When adding noise to an image during the diffusion-based neural compression process, what we are doing is effectively introducing uncertainty and randomness into the image. This means that some of the fine-grained details and features of the image are lost, which can make the image appear more blurry or pixelated.

However, this loss of detail is actually what allows us to compress the image. By reducing the amount of information that we need to store in the compressed representation, we can achieve higher compression rates.

To understand how this works on a technical level, we can think of the image as a matrix of pixel values. Each pixel in the image is represented by a numerical value, which can range from 0 to 255 for an 8-bit grayscale image, or from 0 to 255 for each of the three color channels (red, green, and blue) in a 24-bit color image.

When we add noise to the image, what we are effectively doing is perturbing these pixel values by a certain amount. For example, we might add Gaussian noise to the pixel values, which means that we randomly sample a value from a Gaussian distribution and add it to each pixel value in the image.

By doing this, we are effectively reducing the amount of information that we need to store in the compressed representation, since we no longer need to represent the original pixel values with as much precision. Instead, we can represent the perturbations or noise values with less precision, since the original pixel values can be inferred from these values using the neural network.

Overall, the diffusion-based neural compression process relies on the fact that images are typically redundant and contain a lot of correlated information. By adding noise and progressively degrading the image, we can exploit this redundancy and compress the image by only storing the perturbations or noise values that are needed to reconstruct the original image.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it a bit more clear. To lower the amount of memory you need to represent the noisified image, would you use quantization or some other method? In addition, if you did use quantization, would you apply it after every iteration of Gaussian noise or after applying all the iterations of noise (for ex., if you do Gaussian noise N times to an image, do you do quantization after every iteration or only after all N iterations)? Edit: Or would you even size down and then size up the noisified image?